# Comparing all categories against each other

Tags: pandas

Test Data:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [
    ['green', 7], ['green', 8], ['green', 7],['green', 6], ['green', 8], ['green', 8],
    ['red', 8], ['red', 6], ['red', 7],['red', 2], ['red', 5], ['red', 4],
    ['blue', 8], ['blue', 8], ['blue', 9],['blue', 6], ['blue', 9], ['blue', 9]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Identifier', 'Number'])
```

Ultimately this will be applied to a much larger dataset with many more identifiers, but I tried to pare it down for simplicity. I want to know a good strategy to compare one set within an identifier against each other identifier, specifically by t-test:

```
from scipy.stats import ttest_ind

ttest_ind(
    df[df['Identifier']=='green']['Number'], 
    df[df['Identifier']=='red']['Number'])
```

I need a loop to compare green:red, red:blue, blue:green, etc. with however many identifiers are in the df. In other words, I want a loop that subs into the ttest function above every combination of identifier available in the data frame --> compare green against every other identifier, then compare red against every other identifier, etc.

I had it working perfectly, after hours of quibbling, using a for loop within a for loop, but the file was lost and I'm starting over with only vague memories of how long it took me to figure it out the first time. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in many ways, this is how i did it

```
identifiers = list(set(df['Identifier']))
all_identifier_nums = [df[df['Identifier']==identifier]['Number'] for identifier in identifiers]
all_ttest_inds = []
for i in range(len(identifiers)):
    for j in range(i+1,len(identifiers)):
        all_ttest_inds.append([identifiers[i],
                               identifiers[j],
                               ttest_ind(all_identifier_nums[i],all_identifier_nums[j])])
for ttest_res in all_ttest_inds:
    print(ttest_res)
```